# How use image in api get by axios request in html tags in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, axios

I use axios to get data from the api, now I need to display the image in the `td` tag in HTML, the text response are working fine but the image is not displaying.

my request code is:

```
componentDidMount(){

      var headers = {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "AccessToken":localStorage.TOKEN,
      }

      axios.get(window.$_APIurl+"myProviders/5e463d53e7179a2f011c4104", {headers: headers})
        .then((response) => {   
          console.log(response.data[0].provider.image);
          const doctor = response.data[0].provider.image;
        if(response.data.length > 0)   this.setState({"listOfProviders": response.data});
      })
  }
```

My html to use is:

```
  {this.state.listOfProviders.length > 0 ?
                      <tbody>
                        {this.state.listOfProviders.map((providerData,indx)=>
                          <tr>
                            <td className="font-weight-medium"> <img className="logo" src={doctor} alt="pam-logo" /> {providerData.provider.firstName} {providerData.provider.lastName} </td>
                            <td>{providerData.provider.email}</td>
                            <td>{providerData.provider.phoneNumber}</td>
                            <td>{(providerData.provider.specialities)}</td>
                            <td > {providerData.provider.qbid}</td>
                            <td> Mountain view,Ave </td>
                            <td><Icon icon={editIcon} width="20px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<Icon icon={deleteIcon} width="20px"/></td>

                        </tr>
                        )}
                      </tbody>
```

I need image in src tag.

Comment: Look at this example which has dummy api with image and I have modified the code like yours to display image and its working https://codesandbox.io/s/ajax-request-using-react-and-axios-dpkt4

Answer (score 0):

I guess doctor vairable scoping problem. As you are declaring this  const doctor = response.data[0].provider.image; in componentDidMount but you are accessing from another place.

Comment: Even if i give directly it is not working. There may be something specific regarding images thats where i stuck

Comment: is your image valid .. i mean i declared this and it work
 const doctor = "https://themysteriousworld.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cherry-blossom.webp";

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the use case here. But in my opinion, the variable declared in the componentDidMount() is not accessible in the render method. Just declare that variable as class variable in the constructor and then you can use it using `this.doctor`.

Or instead of declaring the variable you can just read it's value from the iterator. Like, `providerData.provider.image`

Comment: Something specific about image, by giving directly lso not working

Comment: It will be rendered as an image if it is a valid URL. Just debug for its value and check the console also to see if there is some error there regarding image not loaded.

Comment: Console is showing the image name there is no problem with the url

Comment: copy the image and try to get it in the new tab of your browser. And also try to render the URL value in the render function in a <p> tag or something.

Answer (score 0):

create a state variable in constructor

```
this.state = {
    doctor: ''
}
```

after geting response update the image url using setState inside `componentDidMount`

```
this.setState({doctor: response.data[0].provider.image})
```